# Enable RFC1323 on a per socket basis in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, tcp, sockets, rfc

Anybody know if it's possible to enable RFC1323 on a per TCP socket basis in windows?

I know it can be changed system wide via the registry ( http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/tcptune/OStune/winxp/winxp_stepbystep.html )

Also, it seems like this is possible in *nix via:

```
int on=1; 
setsockopt(s,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_RFC1323,&on,sizeof(on));
```

Is there a Windows XP equivalent?

Thanky much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no equivilent of the TCP_RFC1323 socket option in Windows. RFC 1323 support is a global setting.